# If statement between two drop down list. C#

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement, drop-down-menu, messagebox

I have two drop down list.

```
public void DrpDwn_Cuntry()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MySqlCommand sql_country = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Country) FROM Animals", cs);
            cs.Open();

            MySqlDataReader ddlvalue;
            ddlvalue = sql_country.ExecuteReader();

            ddlcountry.DataSource = ddlvalue;
            ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Country";
            ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
            ddlcountry.DataBind();
            ddlcountry.Items.Insert(0, "Choose A Sanctuary");

            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**And**

```
public void DrpDwn_Res()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MySqlCommand sql_residents = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Country) FROM Animals", cs);
            cs.Open();

            MySqlDataReader ddlvalue_residents;
            ddlvalue_residents = sql_residents.ExecuteReader();

            ddlcountry_Res.DataSource = ddlvalue_residents;
            ddlcountry_Res.DataValueField = "Country";
            ddlcountry_Res.DataTextField = "Country";
            ddlcountry_Res.DataBind();
            ddlcountry_Res.Items.Insert(0, "Choose Your Country");

            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I would like a message box to show if the two selected do not match.
for example if the selected country a from first and country b from second message box shows.
I know i am to use a If Else statement I am just not sure how to write it ?

Comment: That depends on a couple of things.  First, what do you mean by "message box"?  The WinForms `MessageBox` doesn't exist in ASP.NET.  Do you mean a JavaScript `alert()`?  Or perhaps some other notification?  Second, do you want this to happen immediately on the client-side interface, or after a form postback?

Comment: I have a button click event. once the button is clicked then if the two drop downs do not match show a alert box.

Comment: winforms or webforms ?

Comment: Webforms asp.net visual studios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `SelectedItem` property of the `DropDownList` Control to achieve this.

**1.** get the `SelectedItem` of the first `DropDownList`.
**2.** get the `SelectedItem` of the second `DropDownList`.
**3.** compare both of the `SelectedItem` values using `Equals()` method.
**4.** if the items do not match , display an `alert` box using `javascript` as `MessageBox` is not bydefault avaialble in Webforms (in webforms it is good to use javascript `alert`) using following Syntax:

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('message here');</script>");
```

**Complete Code:** (Code Behind)

Try This:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(ddlcountry_Res.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Items do not match.');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The message box is available in WinForms, the equivalent in WebForms would be the Alert through javascript (You will need to add the reference on jQuery library)

Here it goes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js "
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

  function compareAndAlert(){
   var value1 = $('#dropDownId').val(); // get the selected value of first dropdown
   var value2 = $('#dropDownId2').val(); // get the selected value of second dropdown
   if (value1 != value2){
     alert("The selected items do not match !"); // If the selected values are not equal display an Alert.
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }

</script>
```

now call this method on the button click

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" onclientclick="javascript:if(compareAndAlert()){}else{return false;}" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Adopted Pet" Height="31px" Width="150px"/>
```

**Update:** This is basically validation and though the Sudhakar's answer is correct but it will lead to unnecessary postback even if the selected values do not match. These type of validations are best served clientside. Do check the update, i have changed the content in onclientclick event of your button

Comment: As my program is in C# can i just place Java Script in to the button click ?

Comment: you dont have the aspx file ??

Comment: put this script into the head tag of your aspx file.

Comment: @tariq : is it worth of mentioning to `include jquery libraries` aswell? as you are calling jquery functions, please correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: so `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" onclientclick="javascript:compareAndAlert();return false;" Text="Adoped Pet" Height="31px" Width="150px" />`

Comment: @Beep , check this now

Comment: @tariq thank you, but have accepted answer. thank you for your answer anyway